# Поиск в другой таблице нескольких совпадений заданного значения

Tags: excel, vba

Есть две таблицы, где в первой таблице столбец A:A - это критерии поиска, а во второй таблице осуществляется поиск при помощи функции `VLOOKUP`. Функция работает правильно, но возвращает всегда только первое совпавшее значение, а мне надо, чтобы для каждого критерия в столбце A:A вернулись все значение из таблицы, где осуществляется поиск.

Нашел решение при помощи формулы массива, но оно работает всегда только для одного критерия (который задан статично), а мне нужно тоже самое, только для всех критерий, как при стандартной работе функции `VLOOKUP`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Первая картинка - это та таблица, где производится поиск. Там есть номера счетов и актуальные остатки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Во второй таблице критерии поиска в столбце акк.намбер. В столбец kbi1 должны возвращаться значения с первой таблицы. Если в первой таблице будет два совпадения, то во второй таблице в столбце kbi1 должно быть два результата друг за другом.

Comment: Если результатов больше одного, куда выводить? Все в одну ячейку? В столбцы правее?

Comment: в идеале так, чтобы они выводились друг за другом(в столбец) то есть вот нашло оно первое совпадение, и вывело в ячейку допустим b3 потом нашло сразу же след. совпадение и вывело в ячейку b4

Comment: Для А3, допустим, выведем в столбец.Но для следующего значения - куда? Вы же написали, что критериев много: "*в первой таблице столбец A:A это критерии поиска*" Или искомое задается и оно одно?

Comment: допустим сейчас функция смотрит на ячейку критерия a2, там есть какой-то номер счета у которого есть два совпадения, в таблице поиска, первое совпадение будет в b2 а второе совпадение будет в b3

Comment: ...а теперь смотрит в а3... и куда помещать данные, если b3 уже занято?

Comment: понял вас. извинясь за неточность. такой ситации не может быть. в стобце критериев a:a заполнены не все ячейки.они отсортированы, и если у критерия есть больше совпадений, то след. ячейки пустые. там что там всегда есть куда поместить данные. важно лишь просто чтобы каждое 2 или 3 совпадение помещалось сразу же в ячейку за первым( в столбец)

Comment: то есть как я и написал раньше. стандартная работа функции vlookup только с той разницой чтоб каждое след. совпадение( если такое есть) помещалось в столбец за первым.  может есть какое-то решение через макрос или еще что-то. просто везде где смотрел, пишут про решение с помощью массива, но там только одно условие.

Comment: Прикрепите к ответу картинки (диапазон А:А и таблица, где происходит поиск). Многострок не надо, 10-15 достаточно.

Comment: @VladStepanov если честно, всё равно непонятно. Приведите пример того, как выглядит *сейчас* таблица и желаемый результат (вывод) с тестовыми данными, показав принцип.

Comment: поменял описание.

Comment: Строка 12. Счет 166053042. Для него выделена одна строка. А если совпадений будет  2 или 3?

Comment: в этом случае не может быть больше чем одно совпадение. больше чем одно совпадение бывает только там где, допустим, sumofmv1 повторяется два и больше раз, столько там и будет совпадений(ровно столько же, сколько повторяется sumofmv1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**VBA поможет.**

```
Sub MultipleSearch()
Dim aNum(), aTabl(), aRes()
Dim i As Long, k As Long, n As Long
    With Worksheets("Лист1") ' лист с таблицей для поиска'
        i = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        aTabl = .Range("A1:G" & i).Value ' таблица в массив'
        ' в А - счет, в G - остаток'
    End With

    With Worksheets("Лист2") ' лист с таблицей (результат)'
        i = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row ' искомые счета в столбце D'
        aNum = .Range("D1:D" & i).Value ' искомые счета в массив'

        ' здесь 3 - максимальное количество возможных значений для одного искомого'
        ReDim aRes(1 To i + 3, 1 To 1) ' задаем размерность массива'
        aRes(1, 1) = .Range("K1").Value ' заголовок столбца К'
    End With

    ' допускаем, что строка 1 - "шапка", ее в обработку не берем'
    For i = 2 To UBound(aNum) ' по искомым данным'
        n = i ' строка для записи найденного'

        For k = 2 To UBound(aTabl) ' по строкам таблицы'
            If aTabl(k, 1) <> Empty Then ' если не пусто'
                If aNum(i, 1) = aTabl(k, 1) Then
                    aRes(n, 1) = aTabl(k, 7): n = n + 1 ' запись найденного'
                End If
            End If
        Next k
    Next i

    ' выгрузка результата на лист в столбец К'
    Worksheets("Лист2").Range("K1").Resize(UBound(aRes), 1).Value = aRes
End Sub
```

*Alt+F11* - вход в редактор *VBA*. Слева дерево проекта. Добавить общий модуль (*Insert-Module*), вставить в него код.

На листе создать любой объект(можно через меню *Вставка-Фигуры*). *ПКМ* на объекте, *Назначить_макрос*, в появившемся списке выделить имя макроса, нажать *ОК*

```
' -----------------
```

Можно **с помощью формулы**. Но на большой таблице возможны тормоза, т.к. формула производит много вычислений. Формула для *К2*.

```
 =ЕСЛИОШИБКА(НАИБОЛЬШИЙ(ЕСЛИ(Лист1!$A$2:$A$9=ПРОСМОТР(9E+307;Лист2!$D$1:D2);Лист1!$G$2:$G$9);СТРОКА(A3)-ПОИСКПОЗ(ПРОСМОТР(9E+307;Лист2!$D$1:D2);$D$1:D2;));)
```

Изменить последнюю строку в диапазонах *Лист1!$A$2:$A$9, Лист1!$G$2:$G$9*

Вводится как формула массива: находясь в строке формул, нажать одновременно *Ctrl+Shift+Enter*. Формула должна обрамиться фигурными скобками.

Протянуть формулу по строкам.

Если мешают нули: меню *Файл-Параметры-Дополнительно-Показать_параметры_листа*, выбрать лист, снять галку *Показывать_нули_в_ячейках*

Формула работает с искомыми данными в числовом формате. Если счета записаны текстом, то формулу нужно усложнять.

Comment: Добрый вечер. Проверил ваш код. Значения в столбец J(KBI1) возвращаются, но почему-то не в соседнюю ячейку напротив номера счета, а на 3 ячейки ниже. Так же до сих пор не возвращаются значения в случае 2-3 совпадений. В ответ добавлю картинку с результатом и кодом. Спасибо за вашу помощь!

Comment: См. комментарий к Вашему ответу

Answer (score 0):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    Sub MultipleSearch()
Dim bf As Boolean
Dim aNum(), aTabl(), aRes(), aString(), aStatus(), aP()
Dim i As Long, k As Long, n, m As Long
With Worksheets("KBSWG")   ' List s tabulkou, kde se hleda
    i = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    aTabl = .Range("A1:H" & i).Value ' tabulka do pole
End With

With Worksheets("Accounting output") ' list s tabulkou, kam se zapisuji vysledky
    i = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row ' hledane ucty v sloupci D
    aNum = .Range("D1:D" & i).Value 'hledane ucty do pole

' tady 3 je maximalni mnozstvi hodnot pro jednu hledany ucet
    ReDim aRes(1 To i + 3, 1 To 1) ' velikost pole
    aRes(1, 1) = .Range("J1").Value ' zahlavi sloupce
End With

With Worksheets("Accounting output")
    i = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    aString = .Range("B1:B" & i).Value
End With

With Worksheets("Accounting output")
    i = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    aStatus = .Range("C1:C" & i).Value
End With

With Worksheets("KBSWG")
    i = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
    aP = .Range("D1:D" & i).Value
End With


For i = 1 To UBound(aNum) ' od 1 do poctu radky tabulky
    n = i 'string pro zapis nalezene hodnoty



    For k = 1 To UBound(aTabl)
      If aString(i, 1) Like "*SumOfMV1*" Then
        If aStatus(i, 1) Like "*BB*" And aP(i, 1) Like "*B*" Or aStatus(i, 1) Like "*BT*" And aP(i, 1) Like "*O*" Then
'If aStatus(i, 1) Like "BB" And aP(i, 1) Like "B" Then bf = True
'If aStatus(i, 1) Like "O" And aP(i, 1) Like "TB" Then bf = True
'If bf Then
           If aTabl(k, 1) <> Empty Then ' kdyz neni prazdna
             If aNum(i, 1) = aTabl(k, 1) Then
               aRes(n, 1) = aTabl(k, 8): n = n + 1 'zapis nalezenych hodnot
'bf = False
        End If
       End If
      End If
     End If

    Next k

Next i

' upload vysledku na list do sloupce J
Worksheets("Accounting output").Range("J1").Resize(UBound(aRes), 1).Value = aRes
```

End Sub

Comment: *For k = 9 To UBound(aTabl)* - начало отсчета не ошибочно? Похоже, в диапазоне на *KBSWG* есть пустоты. В своем коде добавил проверку. =====  Смещение: *aTabl* берем с первой строки, а выгружаете в *J4* (строка перед закрытием процедуры)

Comment: k=9 потому что на листе KBSWG остатки находятся в столбце H  и начинаются с 9 ячейки, i = 5 потому что на листе Acc. output запись начинается с 5 ячейки столбца J ( если я правильно понимаю)

Comment: Я дополнил код: *If aTabl(k, 1) <> Empty Then...End If*. Это для того, чтобы не учитывались пустоты и нормально записывались дубли. О смещении написано в предыдущем комментарии: забирать в массив и выгружать из массива нужно с первой строки

Comment: Спасибо большое. Все работает. Я еще изменил код так, чтобы теперь он смотрел только на строки SumOfMV1. Еще такой вопрос. На листе KBSWG есть столбец P, он принимает только два значения, это либо B(banking) либо O(trading), а на листе acc.output есть столбец Status, в этом столбце все статусы начинаются или на BB(banking) или же на TB(trading). Нужно сделать так чтобы остаток записывался только там, где эти два значения (banking или trading) совпадают. Это как-то возможно?

Comment: Добавить в цикл проверку из двухз *If*: если там *B* и  если здесь *ВВ*, то записываем

Comment: If aStatus(i, 1) Like "*BB*" And aP(i, 1) Like "*B*" Then вот если так записываю первое условие, то оно берет во внимание почему-то только "BB"

Comment: If aStatus(i, 1) Like "BB" And aP(i, 1) Like "B" Or aStatus(i, 1) Like "O" And aP(i, 1) Like "TB" Then === Можно задекларировать и применять переменную: *Dim bf As Boolean*.=== *If aStatus(i, 1) Like "BB" And aP(i, 1) Like "B" Then bf = True* === 
*If aStatus(i, 1) Like "O" And aP(i, 1) Like "TB" Then bf = True* === 
If bf Then (здесь действия по записи и сброс *bf = False*)

Comment: все равно почему-то не работает.  оно смотрит только на первое условие, и возвращает значение везде где есть "BB" при этом не сверяет если в KBSWG у того же счета "B". А во второй половине списка там где в статусе начинается "TB" , в столбце возврата -
 вообще пусто. В мой ответ скинул код, в том состоянии, в каком он у меня сейчас.

Comment: файл у вас на мейле.